# Check if a value exists in database table

Tags: functions, ajax, database, select

I have a custom self made registration form where a user needs to enter his address, I need to check if his address is already added in a custom table(which I have made manually with table prefix).
I am using a custom function in my function.php file.

```
function my_custom_action(){ 
    $myinput = $_POST['address'];

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = 'wp44_predefined_address';
    $result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp44_predefined_address WHERE 'UPPER(Address1)' LIKE 'UPPER(%s)'", $myinput);
    print_r ($result); 
die(); 
}
```

All I am getting is a **Null** value in my console. I have converted the strings into Uppercase also, I have used quotes also.
I have used LIKE, but I also used = , 
I am using `$wpdb->get_row` , I have also used , get_var or get_result.
So what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you have a dropdown of predefined addresses? If yes, you don't need `LIKE`, you only need `=`. If not, I'm afraid it's not that simple, as you'll need to build a fuzzy match library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp44_predefined_address WHERE 'UPPER(Address1)' LIKE 'UPPER(%s)'", $myinput);
```

with this: (just choose the appropriate `$like` based on your requirements)

```
// Properly generate the LIKE query.
$like = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $myinput ) . '%'; // e.g. '%input%'
//$like = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $myinput ); // e.g. '%input'
//$like = $wpdb->esc_like( $myinput ) . '%'; // e.g. 'input%'

$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp44_predefined_address WHERE Address1 LIKE %s", $like);
```

Comment: I used this and it worked.

`global $wpdb;
    
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp44_predefined_address WHERE Address1 LIKE '%".$myinput."%' ");
    echo  $wpdb->num_rows . 'Rows Found <br>';
    print_r ($result);`